# Implementing Real-Time Notifications in React Based on Database Changes

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement React Toastify to show notifications when there are changes in the data displayed within a mapped table in my React component. How can I create a mechanism that detects changes in the data and triggers a toast message when new data is present?

I've implemented React Toastify to notify users when there are changes in the data displayed in a mapped table within my React component. The approach involves fetching data from an API using Axios and comparing it with the existing data. I've used the useEffect hook to trigger a toast message when new data is detected. To prevent the toast from showing on every render, I introduced a check using sessionStorage to ensure it's displayed only once per session.

However, the issue I'm facing is that the toast message appears regardless of whether there are actual changes in the data. It shows up every time I land on the page or refresh it, even when there are no updates to the data. I've attempted to identify the root cause in the code but haven't been successful. Seeking guidance on how to correctly implement the mechanism to display the toast only when there are genuine changes in the fetched data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvi1B.png)

Comment: Please post code and not pictures of code. When the app loads, the `historicalData` is empty before the first request is made, and so it will trigger because the initial state is different to the newly retrieved state. You would have to store the entire previous received state in storage and pull it out in the initial state. But that isn't how you usually solve this sort of thing. Do you control the server? What is the server side database technology in use?